# Conditional Expection on Sum of 2 Random Variables E(X|X+Y)=X+Y?

Tags: probability, gaussian-integral

Suppose X is independent of Y, where X is any distribution, Y is Gaussian (0, $\sigma^2$). Do we have E(X|X+Y)=X+Y?
Thank you!

Comment: What is does it mean if $P(A|B)=P(B)?$

Comment: A independent of B and P (A)=P(B)?

Answer (score 1):

This is definetly not true in general. Note that $\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y)=X+Y$ implies that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(Y|X+Y)=0.
\end{equation}
For a counterexample, let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent Gaussian random variables. Then $\mathbb{E}(Y|X+Y)$ is again Gaussian (and not constantly equal to 0).

Comment: Thank you! Are there any restrictions that we could impose on X to make this statement true?

Comment: The result seems a bit counter-intuitive, what can we say about E(X|X+Y=z) if it does not equal z? 
Is it true then E(X|X+Y=z)=E(X|X~N(z,$\sigma^2$))=z?

Comment: @Kyle, the only trivial example I have in mind is $X=+\infty$ a.s. Then, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X+Y$ is trivial and the result follows.